# Est-ce que c'est correct de dire « j'en marche au travers ?»

Tags: pronoms, prépositions

J'essaye de traduire *I walk through it*. Je sais qu'on peut traduire *through* comme « au travers de ». Dans ce cas, est-ce qu'on peut remplacer « de » et le nom impliqué par « en ?»

Comment: Tu aurais une réponse plus précise si tu donnais plus de contexte. Tout dépend de *it*. Porte ? Mur ? Plancher ?  Surface ?

Comment: @Laure La mer Rouge, que Dieu a fendue.

Comment: La mer rouge c'est une surface donc je traverse la Mer Rouge à pied. Une des réponses donnée par @jiliagre.

Answer (score 3):

« J'en marche au travers » ne peut pas traduire *I walk through it* car « J'en marche... » signifie  « à cause de quelque chose, je marche... » et  « au travers » implique plutôt « à travers une ouverture ».

En fonction du contexte, qui <s>est</s> était malheureusement absent de la question, cette phrase peut être traduite par :

- « Je le parcours en entier ». Cette expression peut s'utiliser au sens figuré, par exemple s'appliquer à un livre.
- « Je m'y promène »
- « Je le traverse à pied »

Edit: Puisqu'il s'agit la traversée de la mer Rouge, la troisième forme convient après accord : « Je **la** traverse à pied »

---

*J'en marche au travers* cannot reasonably translate "I walk through it" as  *J'en marche...* means "because of something, I walk..." and *au travers* would usually mean "through a hole or something".

Depending on the context, which <s>is</s> was unfortunately missing from the question, that sentence might be translated by:

- *Je le parcours en entier* (I go from one end to the other.) This might be used in a figurative way, e.g. a book.
- *Je m'y promène* (I stroll there)
- *Je le traverse à pied* (I cross it by foot)

Edit: Now we know the context is the Red sea crossing, the third form can be used with the correct gender: "Je **la** traverse à pied."

Comment: Pourquoi est-ce que tout le monde me répond en anglais? Est-ce que mon français est si mauvais?

Comment: Non. Je pense que c'est par imitation du premier qui lui a dû employer l'anglais par habitude.

Comment: @GéraudBenazet Il n'y a aucune habitude de répondre en anglais sur French Language. Il est habituel de répondre en français. On utilise l'anglais que si la question est en anglais, et encore pas toujours. Beaucoup apprécient les réponses en français quand ils viennent ici pour apprendre le français.

Comment: @EMBLEM Non, tu te débrouilles très bien en français et tu ne fais pas de fautes. La moindre des politesses serait de te répondre en français. Bienvenue sur French Language.

Comment: @Laure Merci. Une autre chose, au sujet de laquelle j'espère que je ne suis pas obligé de démander une nouvelle question. Pourquoi est-ce que tout le monde tutoie en ligne? Personne ne connait personne.

Comment: @EMBLEM Je t'ai répondu sur le chat. Je vois que tu as assez de réputation pour y accéder. [Lien](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31474355#31474355).

Comment: J'ai répondu en anglais par faute d'inattention à la suite de deux premières réponses en anglais et aussi, plus ou moins inconsciemment, parce que la question semble impliquer de son auteur, qui d'ailleurs a un pseudo en anglais, a une meilleure connaissance de cette langue que du français. Réponse mise à jour avec une version française.

Comment: Ok, I'll answer in French from now on.  Oops !

Comment: J'ai répondu en anglais parce que : 1) je présuppose toujours que la personne qui pose la question n'est pas francophone ; 2) je me dis que je risque de ne pas être compris sur certaines subtilités de la réponse si je réponds en français, et comme mon anglais est basique, je me dis que si j'arrive à expliquer ces subtilités, ce sera forcément compris par la personne.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not make sense at all. "To walk through" would be better translated by "traverser", but it depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

I think in a very particular context, it COULD make sense: 'Ce plancher est tellement fin que j'en marche au travers' (= 'This floor is so thin that I'm walking through it').

But I suppose it's not the context you are talking about.